I want to get the image url from a instagram post url
example, this is a post id : https://www.instagram.com/p/C8_ohdOR/
I want the image src.
first I used selenium for to login and then crawl the image src. so by this I am getting the src. But is there any scalable and fast process to get that.
PS : don't want to use Instaload because it blocks my account permanently.

Welcome, I recommend you to check InsatPy and the guide

Here is the code with the simple requests library, (by the way I saw your target post doesn't exist after trying to visit the link you provided, so I used one of the public posts as a demo)
Note: The demo code contains a login flaw, below code doesn't require authentication if your target post is in the Friends only state then you may have to add your cookie in the header and fb_dtsg token on the body,
Demo Code:
import requests

def sendRequestWithoutlogin(shortcode):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query"
    data = f"variables=%7B%22shortcode%22%3A%22{shortcode}%22%2C%22fetch_tagged_user_count%22%3Anull%2C%22hoisted_comment_id%22%3Anull%2C%22hoisted_reply_id%22%3Anull%7D&doc_id=8845758582119845"
    header = {
        "User-Agent": "YOUR USER AGENT HEADER IS HERE",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    get_image = resp.json()['data']['xdt_shortcode_media']['thumbnail_src']
    print(get_image)

sendRequestWithoutlogin('CmUv48DLvxd')

Output:
https://instagram.fdac34-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.29350-15/320489457_195090603100868_7252177604779913634_n.jpg?stp=c21.0.1197.1197a_dst-jpg_e35_s640x640_sh0.08&_nc_ht=instagram.fdac34-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=oeKMROQospIQ7kNvgHcKTu1&_nc_gid=7d8c6d8c33b6421b8164b2b25690c409&edm=ANTKIIoBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYDsnR02wa0hK8bpkt3Bo_0V1eu3S2_lmZjh87a_ZBHzlA&oe=671D4673&_nc_sid=d885a2

let me know if this is what you want.

yes this is what I want. It works awesome. Thank you so much

welcome, feel free to close the question as accepted, happy coding

can you share the documentation on this api?

My code contains API which is used by Facebook to communicate client to server via desktop application, but if you want to explore Instagram API which is provided for development purpose then follow this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media, let me know which API you want to know about?

actually I am making an instagram bot.
so the issue is when user send any post by using Instagram share button to my bot.
how can i get the url or can access the post anyway.
I was using chatfuel for making bot but chatfuel bot doesn't support this direct share post.

You mean -> user 1 shares the post -> and you want your bot to grab the original post url?

yes... user need to share the post in bot's dm.. then bot access the post somehow..
